# How to query only updated or new rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, data-objects

In my project I need to run a cron job - that will query Table at midnight and create data objects out of the selected rows.

This table will grow in size over a period of time - so intention is to only query (select) - those rows that are new OR rows that have been updated since the previous run.

Is there any way in oracle to do this.

regards

Comment: Does your table have a timestamp field showing when it was last updated; and if not can one be added?

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to have a flag in the table that gets set to TRUE when the row has been processed.  Then the procedure could be made to only run on un-processed (FALSE) rows, regardless of date (in case a midnight run fails for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

the [oracle system change number](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/pseudocolumns007.htm#SQLRF50953)  should help you.
use it in conjunction with a support table:

```
    create table support_table (
         m_pk     master_table.master_pk%TYPE
       , supp_scn NUMBER
    );
```

feed the support table with information about the last change made to the record in the master table once during setup of your tool and henceforth after each of the batch processing runs:

```
    delete
      from support_table
         ;
    insert
      into support_table ( m_pk, supp_scn ) 
           select master_pk
                , ORA_ROWSCN
             from master_table
         ;
```

to check which rows have changed:

```
    select m.master_pk
         , ORA_ROWSCN       scn
      from master_table  m
 left join support_table supp   ON ( supp.m_pk = mthen.master_pk )
     where supp.m_pk IS NULL
        OR supp.supp_scn <> m.master_pk
         ;
```

that result set will contain the `master_pk`s of the changed records and those which have been added since the last check.